# Installing Cloudera Quick start VM on M1 macOs

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Currently I am learning Hadoop. Previously I used lab where I can access the Hadoop ecosystem.

Recently I got M1 Mac and I want to run the same through Cloudera quick start VM.

I do know that it can run in Intel based macOS so, is it possible to run the same in M1 macOS.

Btw, my machine has 8 GB RAM and 256 GB SSD and currently running on macOS Big Sur 11.6

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any further information required on this.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, M1 based Macs doesn't support virtualization. Hence, you cannot install/run Cloudera Quickstart VM on the machine. There are couple of workarounds videos on YouTube for this, but none of them is tried by me as of now.
You can try installing a VM using UTM softwae and let me know too.

Comment: This is partially false. QEMU emulation is supported. What is UTM software?